# Check a checkbox and change the font color of another option

Tags: jquery

Here is my demo code http://jsfiddle.net/Wwdmm/3/

But nothing is happening when I click on `require`. I want to click `require` and then change the font color of `option2` and upon uncheck `option2` removes its class.

What's the mistake? The selection is there.
Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_run_options_0').change(function(){
       if (this.checked){
          alert('checked');
          $('#id_run_options_1').addClass('highlight-option2');
       }else{
          alert('unchecked');
          $('#id_run_options_1').removeClass('highlight-option2');
}});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your class switching using [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_run_options_0').change(function(){
      $('#id_run_options_1').parent().toggleClass('highlight-option2');
  });

  $('#id_run_options_1').change(function(){
      $('#id_run_options_1').parent().toggleClass('highlight-option2');
  });    
});
```

[jsFiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cMd9U/1/)

Comment: Redit Thank you. I changed `change` to `click` but it still didn't turn the font to something else. http://jsfiddle.net/Wwdmm/5/

Comment: Thank you. But why do we need `.parent()`?

Comment: I don't know if I'd use click. Users could tab/enter a checkbox. I think `change` is a better usage.

Comment: @User007: because `id_run_options_1` is the checkbox, but you need to change the color of the label

Comment: @idrumgood: In any case I just tested it and click and change seems to do the same for a checkbox (even for cases you described). Am I missing something?

Comment: From the jQuery documentation: `The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events:

The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element.
The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.`

So I'm not sure why it would be triggering on a keyboard press.

Comment: @idrumgood: I agree with you about the `change` event, I'm just curious though. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/cMd9U/

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Yup, it definitely does. I just don't think it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to change class (hence a color) of a checkbox but you should change the class of a label (its parent element).

Here is the short version of your code:

```
$("#id_run_options_0").change(function() {
  $("#id_run_options_1").parent().toggleClass("highlight-option2", this.checked);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wwdmm/6/

Answer (score 0):

Even this code will work out

```
$('#id_run_options_0').click(function(){
            $('label[for="id_run_options_1"]').toggleClass('highlight-option2');
        });
```

[jsFiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaishak/XdaF6/)